# Restrict some pages being accessed when user phone is offline in PWA using laravel framework

Tags: laravel, progressive-web-apps, laravel-8

I'm using https://github.com/silviolleite/laravel-pwa package for PWA in my laravel web application. I've some login panel and dashboard related stuff for web app user.
I want to restrict these web app pages being accessed by user when user is in offline or more specifically when user phone is not connected to internet.

Framework: Laravel ^8.0
PWA Package: https://github.com/silviolleite/laravel-pwa

Comment: You can do this through JavaScript, e.g. [Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) to trigger a redirect or an overlay or something

Comment: Thanx @apokryfos for replying. I just want to know that all script is done in service worker or any other file?

Comment: I think the place to put this is in the service worker, you might need to publish the laravel-pwa assets to be able to modify it though. I've never used that package so I'm not sure

Comment: Ok Thank you @apokryfos. I'm going through their documentation but fail to find what I want. I've publish the package already and going to work as you suggested. thanks a lot.